# access rules by IP for all roles

Tags: yii, yii2

on Yii2, I'm trying to limit the `create` action to **only allow approved IPs** no matter if user is logged in or not.

Here is my code

```
 'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create'],
                    'rules' => [
                         [   
                             'actions' => ['index','view'],
                             'allow' => true,
                             'roles' => ['@'],
                         ],
                         [   
                            'actions' => ['create'],
                            'allow' => true,
                            'ips' => Yii::$app->params['adminIPs'], 
                            'roles' => ['?','@'],       
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
```

if the user is logged in, and is not an allowed ip. It shows the `forbidden permission` page but if the user if `NOT`  logged in,  it redirects to the login page.

How do i get it to show the 403 forbidden page for both scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when the rule denies access the [`AccessControl::denyAccess()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/AccessControl.php#L153) method is called. If the user is guest (not logged in) they are redirected to login page by this method. If you want to return 403 Forbidden page instead you have to override this behavior by using [`AccessRule::$denyCallback`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accessrule#$denyCallback-detail) property.

Also, you need to set the `denyCallback` property for rule that denies access, not for the one that allows access.

For example:

```php
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::class,
    'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create'],
    'rules' => [
        // ...
        [   
            'actions' => ['create'],
            'allow' => true,
            'ips' => Yii::$app->params['adminIPs'], 
        ],
        [
             'actions' => ['create'],
             'allow' => false,
             'denyCallback' => function() {
                 throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'You are not allowed to perform this action.'));
             }
        ]
    ],
],
```

Because the rule matches everything, you need to make sure that it's last rule for `create` action next rules won't be reached once this one matches.

Comment: i tried this before, same results. any idea whats causing it to go to the login page instead?

Comment: i also included `use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;` too

Comment: I've realised where the problem is and edited my answer. You have to put the `denyCallback` into rule that actualy denies access, not to the one that allows it.

Comment: `.'actions'` typo here. changed it to `'actions'` and it works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to restrict access by IP and don't care if the user is logged in or not you can just omit the roles.

```php
'access' => [
  'class' => AccessControl::className(),
  'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create'],
  'rules' => [
    //....
    [   
      'actions' => ['create'],
      'allow' => true,
      'ips' => Yii::$app->params['adminIPs'],    
    ],
  ],
],
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, any idea whats causing it to go to the login page instead?